# Хранение и вывод страниц с кодом

Tags: php

Вечер добрый.
Написал простенький сайт, в нем 10-12 страниц. Страницы выводятся из базы данных такими запросами:

```
index.php?page=contacts
```

Дело в том, что есть страницы, которые содержат код, к примеру, php-скрипт обратной связи или динамический каталог запчастей, который также формируется согласно get запросам. Сейчас я их вывожу через такие запросы:

```
index.php?do=parts
index.php?do=contacts
```

И страницы загружаются не из базы, а из php-файлов в директории сервера.

Если  страницы с кодом хранить в базе данных, то их потом очень неудобно редактировать. Посоветуйте, как проще всё организовать.

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: По хорошему совет будет "используйте фреймворк или CMS". Но если вы сформулируете свой вопрос более конкретно, то можно и решение полегче найти. 

Как вы хотите, чтобы было? — держать php код в файлах, а весь не-php контент в базе?

Comment: Хотелось знать как вообще подобное реализовывается.

Comment: Для начала описали бы, чем у вас **do** и **page** различаются по обработчику.  
Банальное условие (**if**) вам не подходит?

Comment: Когда page идет загрузка страницы (ключевые слова, контент) из базы через шаблон defaul.php, когда do идет просто подгрузка файла с кодом из директории.

Comment: По хорошему в базе нужно хранить не страницы, а информацию, которая через переменные выводится на страницу, например, через циклы. Если у вас на сайте есть каталог и есть форма обратной связи, то сайт уже не такой простенький, как правильно написал @Sergiks, используйте фреймворк (CMS не буду советовать, ну люблю я их), для такого сайта очень хорошо подойдёт Yii

Comment: Контентом они же только отличаются? В базу пихаешь содержание для каждой страницы, создаешь один индекс и из базы контент по get[do] выбираешь.